# Flutter. Receive Firebase notifications during integration tests

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-test

Flutter notification has a handler that works with received Firebase notification, set up the following way:

```
  messaging.configure(
      onMessage: messHandler,
      onLaunch: messHandler,
      onResume: messHandler);
```

handler works perfectly during manual testing but `messHandler` isn't called for integration tests with `driver_extension`.